# Is there a ".d" directory to use to load modules at boot time, opposed to /etc/modules?

Tags: boot, kernel, modprobe

I am automating some configurations on my systems using Puppet (however, that is not really relevant here). For a group of machines I want to load a kernel module at boot time. The most elegant way seems to edit `/etc/modules` and add one on an individual line. However, I would like to use separate files in a "`.d`" directory structure for easier maintainability, rather than having Puppet editing a file.

For modprobe and specifying the options for or blacklisting modules, there's `/etc/modprobe.d/`, but what's the most elegant way for actually loading modules at boot time using a single new file? Basically, I'm looking for the non-existing `/etc/modules.d/` directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory you are looking for is

```
/etc/modules-load.d
```

For example, to always load the `nf_conntrack_pptp` kernel module, add `nf_conntrack_pptp` to `/etc/modules-load.d/pptp.conf`. The filename doesn't matter, but I'm guessing the convention or requirement is that it ends in `.conf`.

This is implemented for older Ubuntu versions (without systemd) using a SysVinit script in `/etc/init.d/kmod`. For newer systemd-versions (15.04+), systemd handles this. Read the documentation `man 5 modules-load.d`.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be a systemd-thing, though. So this will only work in the very recent Ubuntu releases (15.04+). https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html See also this Q&A on Unix.SE: [What's the difference of `/etc/modules-load.d` and `/etc/modules`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189696/23363)

Comment: `/etc/modules-load.d` works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit desktop, but I don't recall ever installing systemd... maybe there's some kind of systemd/upstart bridge in 14.04?

Comment: You're right! It's `/etc/init.d/kmod` which comes from Debian, working with SysVinit too. Upstart runs it too. Great! I can improve your answer and accept it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put additional .conf files in /etc/modprobe.d/ to do module loading as well (even though the default files in there are all about blacklisting things).

You may be able to just put the module name on a line by itself, or if you need more complex behaviour, you can use 'install' at the beginning of a line.  From the manpage:

```
install modulename command...
    This is the most powerful primitive: it tells modprobe to run your command 
    instead of inserting the module in the kernel as normal.
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/modprobe.conf.5.html

Comment: Are you sure about that "to do module loading as well"? Does not seem to work for me. I've put a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf` containing one line `acpiphp`, but the module isn't loaded on reboot. Same when prepending it with `install`. Additionally, when modprobing manually, now getting warnings: `WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'acpiphp'`

Comment: I'm not sure about putting it on a line by itself, but I'm positive that you can load modules using a line that starts with "install".

Comment: Nope, as I said, same when prepending with `install`: `WARNING: /etc/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'install'`

Comment: you might have to write your own startup script, at that point.

Answer (score -1):

When using a file in **/etc/modules.d** directory
you have to use **install** directive.

Since "install" is expecting **[module_name] [command]**

```
install your_module /bin/true
```

will do the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and let you know. Do you have any source for this? The only source I find using Google on `modules.d install` is your answer (rest of the results is irrelevant noise).

Comment: Didn't work for me.