# Can't connect to PPTP VPN with ufw enabled on Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.18

Tags: networking, kernel, network-manager, vpn, firewall

Suddenly VPN disconnected and can't reconnect no longer on kernel 3.18.1, so I try to install kernel 3.18.2 but my problem still exist. But I can connect to VPN with 3.14 kernel easily.

The output of syslog:

```
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 8741
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN connection 1' (Connect) reply received.
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pppd[8742]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pppd[8742]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pppd[8742]: Using interface ppp0
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pppd[8742]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/25
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pptp[8747]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jan 11 17:43:51 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Jan 11 17:43:52 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jan 11 17:43:52 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jan 11 17:43:52 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 37038).
Jan 11 17:43:53 DEMON vnstatd[1509]: Interface "ppp0" enabled.
Jan 11 17:43:55 DEMON kernel: [  921.480993] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=74:de:2b:02:0b:da:50:1c:bf:61:6f:41:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.74.15 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64925 PROTO=47 
Jan 11 17:43:55 DEMON kernel: [  922.096723] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=74:de:2b:02:0b:da:50:1c:bf:61:6f:41:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.74.15 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64926 PROTO=47 
Jan 11 17:43:57 DEMON kernel: [  923.911774] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=74:de:2b:02:0b:da:50:1c:bf:61:6f:41:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.74.15 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64927 PROTO=47 
Jan 11 17:44:16 DEMON kernel: [  943.116984] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=74:de:2b:02:0b:da:50:1c:bf:61:6f:41:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.74.15 LEN=54 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64937 PROTO=47 
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pppd[8742]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pppd[8742]: Connection terminated.
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pppd[8742]: Modem hangup
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pptp[8747]: nm-pptp-service-8741 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pptp[8747]: nm-pptp-service-8741 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pppd[8742]: Exit.
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON pptp[8761]: nm-pptp-service-8741 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> Policy set '4r@z31' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jan 11 17:44:22 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jan 11 17:44:23 DEMON vnstatd[1509]: Interface "ppp0" disabled.
Jan 11 17:44:28 DEMON NetworkManager[7443]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

**UPDATE**

My problem solved by disabling ufw, could you please help me to solve this conflict of firewall and vpn?

**UPDATE 2**

So I try to add

```
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

into `/etc/ufw/before.rules` but my problem still exist.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is caused by a change for security reason in kernel 3.18 [[1]](http://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=142195881513706&w=2). There are two ways to fix this.

First approach is adding this rule to the file `/etc/ufw/before.rules` before the line `# drop INVALID packets ...`

```
-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

Second approach is manually loading the `nf_conntrack_pptp` module. You can do this by running

```
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
```

To load this module on every boot on Ubuntu, add it to the file `/etc/modules`.

Comment: Don't forget to restart ufw to reload the new configuration.

Comment: You save my life!!!

Comment: @wwwhizz You mean `sudo ufw reload` ? That seems to do it, once I found the correct part of the file to add that rule to.

Comment: I wonder, how could this sort of thing be done through the gufw ui?

Comment: "nf_conntrack_pptp" did not work by me, but allowing proto 47 (GRE), as the OP writes, it did.

Answer (score 17):

For [ufw >= 0.34-2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall#Available_Versions_in_supported_versions_of_Ubuntu), a simple solution is:

```
sudo ufw allow proto gre from [PPTP gateway IP address]
```

Comment: Answers should be as complete as possible and stand on their own - if you just want to add something to an existing answer please use a comment.

Comment: @Draco woah there! There is no call to insult other users. And we expect all users to act with civility here.

Comment: I'll just mention for future visitors: this solution is complete and not intended to be added on to any of the others.

Comment: Didn't even need to restart ufw, worked right after adding the rule.

Comment: your method worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Add `nf_conntrack_pptp` to `/etc/modules-load.d/pptp.conf`

### One liner

```
echo nf_conntrack_pptp | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/pptp.conf
```

### Explanation

The accepted answer works for me, especially the 2nd suggestion--loading the `nf_conntrack_pptp` kernel module--as opposed to modifying my iptables firewall. My laptop firewall is otherwise unmodified. `sudo ufw enable` without exceptions is nice and clean. But **I don't like editing `/etc/modules` by hand**... future package upgrades may have conflicts. `/etc/modules-load.d/` provides an upgrade-friendly and more easily automatable way to load the module.

### See also

[Is there a ".d" directory to use to load modules at boot time, opposed to /etc/modules?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228337/is-there-a-d-directory-to-use-to-load-modules-at-boot-time-opposed-to-etc-m/738010#738010)

### Parting shot: Do not use PPTP!

- https://www.schneier.com/cryptography/pptp/faq.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol
- http://www.howtogeek.com/211329/which-is-the-best-vpn-protocol-pptp-vs.-openvpn-vs.-l2tpipsec-vs.-sstp/

Try openvpn instead.