# pptpd in 16.04: can't establish the connection

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, vpn, pptp, pptpd

I can install pptpd in 14.04 using this short (9 steps) script:
https://github.com/MdNor/digital-ocean-pptp-vpn/blob/master/ubuntu

But it doesn't work in 16.04: Windows client prints that it can't establish the connection.

What step should be added for 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Ubuntu 16.04 - even if you had a slightly newer kernel set in 14.04 it would do this. [See workaround here which involves turning on nf_conntrack_pptp kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572497/).