# How to connect to PPTP VPN in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, vpn, pptp

I am trying to set a VPN client to connect through the insecure PPTP protocol to a VPN server. I was only given a gateway, an user and a password.

I followed the classic tutorials in which you create the VPN connection through the network manager and everything works with any problem, but as always, in my case the connection cannot be established. This is what I set in PPTP advanced options:

- I only allow MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2 authentication methods (PAP, CHAP and EAP disabled).
- I use any MPPE Encryption (stateful disabled).
- I allow Deflate and TCP header compressions (BSD disabled).

And this is what `syslog` shows when I try to connect:

```
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.7422] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="b128925d-79d3-422c-ae8d-92b6dba4c237" name="My VPN" pid=1715 uid=1000 result="success"
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.7460] vpn-connection[0x5573efe6a110,b128925d-79d3-422c-ae8d-92b6dba4c237,"My VPN",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 22957
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.7540] vpn-connection[0x5573efe6a110,b128925d-79d3-422c-ae8d-92b6dba4c237,"My VPN",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.8158] vpn-connection[0x5573efe6a110,b128925d-79d3-422c-ae8d-92b6dba4c237,"My VPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
pppd[22961]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
NetworkManager[665]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
pppd[22961]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
pppd[22961]: Using interface ppp0
NetworkManager[665]: Using interface ppp0
NetworkManager[665]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
pppd[22961]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/5
systemd-udevd[22965]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.8246] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
pptp[22966]: nm-pptp-service-22957 log[main:pptp.c:353]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.8329] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640744.8330] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
pppd[22961]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
NetworkManager[665]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
NetworkManager[665]: Connection terminated.
pppd[22961]: Connection terminated.
charon: 12[KNL] interface ppp0 deleted
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640775.8517] vpn-connection[0x5573efe6a110,b128925d-79d3-422c-ae8d-92b6dba4c237,"My VPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1552640775.8532] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
pppd[22961]: Terminating on signal 15
NetworkManager[665]: Terminating on signal 15
NetworkManager[665]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-22957 (pid 22964) terminated with signal 15
NetworkManager[665]: Modem hangup
pppd[22961]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-22957 (pid 22964) terminated with signal 15
pppd[22961]: Modem hangup
pppd[22961]: Exit.
```

I was googling a lot and trying almost everything I read to solve this problem, especially the posts about the following errors:

- *link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable*.
- *The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated*.
- *no ifupdown configuration found*.

But I have not found a solution yet. Can anyone give me a hint about this? Any comment could help me a lot, since finding errors when connecting to VPN servers is not my best. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case it turned out to be ufw blocking everything.

in this link there where simple ideas. In ufw you can do

"sudo ufw allow proto gre from " to allow connections from

[Can't connect to PPTP VPN with ufw enabled on Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572497/cant-connect-to-pptp-vpn-with-ufw-enabled-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-kernel-3-18)

Not sure if your error showed up in my case, but it's worth a try